# What is the command (if there is one) to make all blocks in a world unbreakable against explosions?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure world that is players versus monsters. I understand adventure mode doesn't allow *players* to break blocks, but not *monsters*. I would like to keep creepers, but it seems to do this I would have to build every thing out of obsidian and bedrock so the creeper explosions don't ruin my paths and rooms! So, what command might be used to make every block in the world unbreakable instead?

Comment: I am running Minecraft 1.9.2

Comment: Does the /gamerule mobGriefing false  allow creepers to still do damage to players in 1.9.2 though? @Trent Hawkins

Comment: mobGriefing determines whether creepers, zombies, endermen, ghasts, withers, ender dragons, rabbits, sheep, and villagers should be able to change blocks and whether villagers, zombies, skeletons, and zombie pigmen can pick up items. They can still do damage to players.

Comment: perfect...this is a duplicate then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the base problem you stated (`I would like to keep creepers, but it seems to do this I would have to build every thing out of obsidian and bedrock so the creeper explosions don't ruin my paths and rooms!`):**

Just run the command `/gamerule mobGriefing false`, it'll prevent creepers from exploding.

**For your final question (`So, what command might be used to make every block in the world unbreakable instead?`):**

None. Try mods.

Comment: does "/gamerule mobGriefing false"  still do damage to players or just disables the exploding creepers altogether? @ardaozkal

Comment: @MinerBoyJosh It disables the exploding creepers.